# Error when using tinker to generate Users and Posts (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel-8

I have the following BlogPostFactory

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;


class BlogPostFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'title' => $this->faker->sentence,
            'body' => $this->faker->paragraph(30),
            'user_id' => User::factory(),
        ];
    }
}
```

I've been trying to use tinker to generate posts and users,

```
 \App\Models\BlogPost::factory()->count(10)->create();
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
PHP Error:  Class "Database\Factories\User" not found in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\example\database\factories\BlogPostFactory.php on line 19
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the namespace on the `User` class.
By default PHP takes the current namespace `namespace Database\Factories;`, hence the error.

[Name resolution rules](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php)

> 6. For unqualified names, if no import rule applies and the name refers to a class-like symbol, the current namespace is prepended. For
>    example, new C() inside namespace A\B resolves to name A\B\C.

Instead of: (*Unqualified name*)

```php
// ...
'user_id' => User::factory(),
// ....
```

Use this: (*Fully qualified name*)

```php
// ...
'user_id' => \App\Models\User::factory(),
// ...
```

##### Addendum

Don't forget to restart your current tinker session. (*Close the current one  (`exit;`) and open a new tinker session (`php artisan tinker`)*).

Comment: I tried this but I'm still getting the same error message. :(

Comment: @rubenf01 Try restarting your current tinker session.